# file could not be downloaded in IE 11 when a compressed(gzipped) response is sent to the client

Tags: java, spring-mvc, internet-explorer, download, struts-1

I am trying to download a file from an application through two frameworks. one with struts 1(older framework) and the other with Spring MVC(migrated from old).In Spring migrated application it is showing  file could not be downloaded in IE 11 when a compressed(gzipped) response is sent to the client. It is showing "File could not be downloaded". It works fine in chrome as well as in older struts framework. Also if the response is not compressed, file gets downloaded successfully on IE as well on Spring MVC. I cannot really identify the cause here. Requesting some guidance and help to identify this problem.

Request headers is

```
<code>
    Request URL: //edited
       Request Method: POST
       Status Code: 200 / OK
     - Request Headers
       Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
       Accept-Language: en-US
       Authorization: Basic YW3Rt2aW46dG4V3zdD5EyMz6Q=
       Cache-Control: no-cache
       Connection: Keep-Alive
       Content-Length: 3521
       Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
       Cookie: JSESSIONID=urVBPpjD3QrP6KhkqCK4r8KSAuvKFSVPdp-UXyz-FYSz4W0cQmV9sh!4524586920
       Host: localhost:7001
       Referer: //edited
       User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
</code>
```

Below is the response headers

```
<code>
     Response Headers
       Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store
       Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Closed DSP01 CRD0037_2019-12-26_133924.csv"
       Content-Encoding: gzip
       Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8
       Date: Thu, 26 Dec 2019 08:09:23 GMT
       Expires: 0
       Pragma: no-cache
       Transfer-Encoding: chunked
</code>
```

particular code where compression is done

```
<code>
    if (canUseGzip) {
          response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
         GZIPOutputStream out = new GZIPOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
         pw = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
    } else {
         pw = response.getWriter();
    }
</code>
```

I tried different possibilities and when I tried to explicitly set content-length header ,say,

```
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(1024));
```

the file got downloaded successfully in IE. When I googled, I found transfer-encoding and content-length are mutually exclusive and former is already on the response. I don't know why adding content-length worked here and it was required only on the Spring migrated code. File gets downloaded successfully on older struts framework without mentioning the content-length header.
Is there anything specific I am missing here? Is there any other permanent solution as well?
Also how to correctly set the content length? I randomly tried with 1024 and it may fail for some other data.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why are you gripping the file yourself? That’s your web servers job. In the best case, your own code is likely slower and buggier than the web servers so you’re just introducing debt. In the worst case your content gets double wrapped - causing weird and wonderful behaviour.

Comment: Based on my searching results, I found this information. This happens if the downloaded file does not have the same size as the content-length header. This should not happen under normal condition, unless there is a bug in the server that does not give the full file, or a proxy or so cuts the connection.

Comment: @BoristheSpider tried with that as well. still same impact. on Spring migrated code ,File couldn't be downloaded error is shown on internet explorer.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT in that case, how the file is getting downloaded in struts framework? I have issue only in Spring migrated code and in IE only as well! setting content-length header fixes the issue , but I am not sure what and how should I set it or even whether it is mandatory or not.

Comment: I suggest you to specifically set the content-length for IE and set it as per your maximum file size may help to work around this issue for IE browser.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT thanks for the suggestion. How ever I would like to have know the reason behind why it is working in Struts and not Spring that might lead to an answer rather than setting the Content length header. Also I am not sure how to accurately set the Content length header either. Any help in this regard is also appreciated.

Comment: I will try to find the reason for it. As soon as I get any information, I will try to provide you. Thanks for your understanding.